# Insert non-rectangular selection

Tags: visual-block

I repeatedly have the following situation, and wonder how it can be handled better than I do it now. These lines must be merged

```
/path;text
/path;text
/path;text
```

with these:

```
/subdir
/longsubdir
/longlongsubdir
```

Desired result:

```
/path/subdir;text
/path/longsubdir;text
/path/longlongsubdir;text
```

What I do now is to mark and yank the second block as a block, go to the first semicolon in the first block, and press P. Result is:

```
/path/subdir        ;text
/path/longsubdir    ;text
/path/longlongsubdir;text
```

But this is obviously not what I want. How can I avoid the extra blanks?

Answer (score 5):

With the latest Vim version [8.2.2914](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2914), you can now simply paste without adding padding using the `zp` command.

Comment: have just tried it and it works the same as with p/P

Comment: nvm,  `set virtualedit=block` interferes here

Comment: @BLayer could you have been experiencing this feature/bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8301

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can avoid extra blanks...

I would do it this way:

1. select `/subdir/` and other dirs with `<C-v>` + motion
2. delete it
3. go to `/path`'s and paste befor `;`
4. select para and remove spaces with `vip:norm! f diw`

There probably might be a better way with or without plugins, idk.

PS, ofc the last command that deletes the spaces should depend on what you end up having in a merged text. You can go with a safer option `vip:s/ \+//g`

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you make this gif/animation? A moving picture speaks a million words :-)

Comment: @Chris ScreenToGif

Answer (score 1):

Here's a programmatic way of doing it. It's a bit complicated, but it only took me 5 minutes of trial and error to get right :)

Here's the start:

```
/path;text
/path;text
/path;text
/subdir
/longsubdir
/longlongsubdir
```

The key is to try to `:join` the matching lines with a `:global` command. We can do a touch up of the ordering and such later.

A first attempt might be `:global/;/+3move. | -join!`, which says to do the following for each line containing a semi-colon: move the line 3 lines down to below the current line, then join them without spaces.

The problem is, after the lines start moving, 3 isn't the right number anymore! There are various ways to calculate the right offset (and you might be able to get away with a good search pattern if you're careful, something like `/[^;]*`), but I chose to just go with a counter.

Initialize the counter with 3, which works for the first one (3 for the number of `/path;text` lines you have):

```
let lines = 3
```

Then, on each run of the `:global`, we use the counter for the offset and also decrement the counter:

```
:global/;/execute print('+%dmove.', lines) | -join! | let lines -= 1
```

This isn't quite right. The last step is to touch up the ordering (we end up with the text in the middle).

We can do this afterwards using a whole-file substitute, but I found it fine to do as part of the `:global`. We just swap the order of two groups:

```
:global/;/execute printf('+%dmove.', lines) | -join! | substitute,\v(;[^/]+)(/.*),\2\1, | let lines -= 1
```

Or, as one long command:

```
:let lines = 3 | global/;/execute printf('+%dmove.', lines) | -join! | substitute,\v(;[^/]+)(/.*),\2\1, | let lines -= 1
```

and with abbreviations/short names

```
:let c = 3 | g/;/exec printf('+%dm.', c) | -j! | s,\v(;[^/]+)(/.*),\2\1, | let c -= 1
```

Final result:

```
/path1/subdir;text
/path2/longsubdir;text
/path3/longlongsubdir;text
```